# Does jTemplates foreach preserve the ordering of the collection?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, jtemplate

My collection is ordered alphabetically, but when I assign the collection and load the html using jquery jtemplates, things are coming out un-ordered.

```
  {#foreach $T.results as r}
      <li>{$T.r.Name}</li>
 {#/for}
```

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Nope

What server code are you using to prepare and send the collection?